# java: encoding presence of a tag using bit

Tags: java, encoding, bit

I have a class A that could have up to 50 tags and instances of A appears many times in a list (think of a few hundred thousands) that is stored as json + compressed. Tags name and value are freeform text, up to 1024 characters long each. Distinct number of different tags in a same list is capped at 50.

At the moment, i am not looking to move to other types of encoding such as protobuf or using different compression algorithm.

To reduce the size of the stored data, i am thinking about using bit encoding to capture presence of certain tags. For example, before serializing data, scan the list of instances of A and collect all tagName:tagValue sets and assign number to each distinct tag as following

```
1: tagA:valueA
2: tagB:valueB
4: tagC:valueC
8: tagD:valueD
16: ...
```

and each instance would have long field that represent bit value, so for example, if an A has tagA, tagC, tagD, it would have

```
long tagSet = 13; //(0001 | 0100 | 1000 = 13)
```

and I would also maintain an array of strings as a map. This way, raw tag strings are not repeated in each instance of A.

Is there a better way to do this such as some built in java collection or even completely different encoding mechanism?

Comment: Do you know the complete set of possible tags at compile time? In that case you can model the tags as Enum values and use `java.util.EnumSet` to store them; EnumSet uses bits internally.

Comment: it is not known at compile time